# Ajax and PHP form : window still refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

thank you for those who read this post ! 
I have a contact form on my website, and I want the window doesn't be refreshing when a user submit it, but it still refreshing in spite of I use Ajax with POST method ..

Here is the code (html) :

```
                <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Complete name" name="name" id="name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Object" name="objet" id="object" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <textarea rows="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here ..." name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-am" id="sending_form">Envoyer mail</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

the PHP file :

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $object = $_POST['objet'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-to : $name <$email>\nX-Mailer:PHP";

  $subject="$objet";
  $destinataire="my_mail@mail.com";
  $body="$message";

  mail($destinataire,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
?>
```

and the Ajax call :

```
$('#sending_form').click(function(){
    var data = {
        email: $('#email').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        objet: $('#object').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_mail.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        sucess: function(msg) {
            alert('Email sent');
        }
    });
});
```

I hope I give you all necessaries informations !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the default behavior of the `click` event, which is the submission of the form:

```
$('#sending_form').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var data = {
        email: $('#email').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        objet: $('#object').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_mail.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email sent');
        }
    });
});
```

> Node: the `e` variable that was added inside the `function` parameters.

If you don't do that - the default action that the browser will do is submit the form (and this is what you want to prevent).

Comment: Thank you ! it work, I have to wait 10 minutes to mark your answer as accepted but I am waiting for :)

Comment: Sure :) you are welcome. You can also vote-up the answer before you accept it.

Comment: Done ! I have one last question, do you know why I haven't any response (I don't see the alert when the form is submitted, that is in the success attribute of the ajax call) ?

Comment: Might be a problem with your php and you didn't get a success return from there. Open the developers tool bar and check the request and response.

Comment: Need to add error handling on your ajax call as you never know what the user will submit in a contact form.

Answer (score 2):

> I have one last question, do you know why I haven't any response (I don't see the alert when the form is submitted, that is in the success attribute of the ajax call)?

It seems that you misspelled 'success', should be:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "get_mail.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email sent');
        }
    });
```

Note the second 'c'.

Comment: Hahah! :) Good catch for that one. Sometimes it's hard to catch spelling errors in coding.